# How to override scoped styles in Vue components?

Tags: css, webpack, vue.js, vuejs2

Let's save I have a `.Vue` component that I grab off of Github somewhere. Let's call it CompB and we'll add a single CSS rule-set there for a blue header:

**CompB.Vue** (a dependency I don't own, perhaps pulled from Github)

```
<template>
  ...
</template>

<script>
  ...
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
  .compb-header {
    color: blue;
  }
</style>
```

I plan to nest CompB into my own project's CompA. Now what are my options for overriding the scoped rule?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

After playing around a bit, I think I've got a good approach.

1. Global overrides

   For situations where I want to override the rules in all cases for CompB I can add a rule-set with more specificity like this: `#app .compb-header { .. }`. Since we always only have one root (`#app`) it's safe to use an ID in the rule-set. This easily overrides the scoped rules in CompB.
2. Parent overrides

   For situations where I want to override both the global and scoped rules. Thankfully VueJS allows adding both a scoped and unscoped style block into a .Vue file. So I can add an even more specific CSS rule-set. Also notice I can pass a class into CompB's props since Vue provides built-in class and style props for all components:

   ```
   // in CompA (the parent)

   <template>
     ...
     <!-- Vue provides built-in class and style props for all comps -->
     <compb class="compb"></compb>  
   </template>

   <script>
     ...
   </script>

   <style lang="scss">
     #app .compb .compb-header { 
       color: red; 
     }
   </style>

   <style lang="scss" scoped>
     ...
   </style>
   ```

   *(note: You can get more specific and make the class you pass into CompB have a more unique name such as `.compa-compb` or some hash suffix so there is no potential for collision with other components that use CompB and a class `.compb`. But I think that might be overkill for most applications.)*
3. And of course CompB may provide its own additional props for adjusting CSS or passing classes/styles into areas of the component. But this may not always be the case when you use a component you don't own (unless you fork it). Plus, even with this provided, there is always those situations where you are like "I just want to adjust that padding just a bit!". The above two solutions seem to work great for this.

Answer (score 6):

You will need to add more specificity weight to your css. You have to wrap that component in another class so you can override it. Here is the complete code

```
<template>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <comp-b>...</comp-b>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import CompB from 'xxx/CompB'

export default {
  components: {
    CompB
  }
}
</script>

<style>
  .wrapper .compb-header {
    color: red;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: I think the *best* solution is, send PR to that library and remove `scoped`, use BEM or just add a prefix to class name

Comment: Yeah, I still find myself using BEM even in these scoped situations. But recently I've found that scoped may not be as useful as I originally thought. Funny, I actually did an issue recently on a github package asking for just that (BEM and no "scoped").

Comment: BTW, is this something React handles better (for example, can you pass in styles to React components to override the default ones?)?

Comment: scoped will be useful for the components your owned (not a published library), add scoped and you don't need to add class everywhere, no more `<button class="button">`, just write css to tag names `h1 { ... } button { ... }`

Comment: I read in VueJS documentation that you still need to add classes for performance reasons in these scoped situations.

Comment: See bottom of the documentation page here: https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/features/scoped-css.html #4 in the Notes list.