# Vue - change contents in scoped <style>?

Tags: css, vue.js

What would be great is if I found a way to change the contents of a `<style>` block in my Vue component with some Vue variables.

The common question and answer around this involve using in-line styles, or using javascript to access a `.style` property, but I wish to change slider tracks and pseudo elements much like this question here: [.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb needed in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48297265/slider-webkit-slider-thumb-needed-in-javascript)

If the official Vue position is that `<style>`s are static, etc - does anyone else wish they had some system like `<style scoped dynamic>` where the contents of the style sheet can be controlled by Vue?

Comment: You can put your styles into JS and then expose them via a scoped slot. for example you could have: 
```<myComponent scoped-slot={'styles'} :styleProp="incomingStyle">```
similar to have `isActive` styles.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the kind of contents your "incomingStyle" would have?

Answer (score 0):

I am able to get working results per this answer ([How to override scoped styles in Vue components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41133833/how-to-override-scoped-styles-in-vue-components)) with the parent component using a non-scoped  which has selectors that overtake the importance of the child component's styles.
As the answer said, using "#app" as the start of the selector does the job - the stumbling block for me was simply adding a non-scoped style block to the parent component.

However it isn't so versatile and I'm looking to learn what "putting styles into JS" means and whether it would also provide the method to override the pseudo-element styles.